NA omit only select rows that have NA's
In the example below, if I do na.omit on df, then it omits rows where d has a value of 10 and 12.
Is there a way to do an na.omit with a condition that both column c and d have to have an NA for the entire row to be omitted? That was I will still have 2 NA's in the c column because a, b and d has data for it.
a <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
b <- c(2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20)
c <- c(0.1, 3, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
d <- c(3, 6, 9, 10, 12, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(a, b, c, d))

df
na.omit(df)


Here is a base R way to do this by using the [ subsetting function and
a logical statement.  na.omit() is working exactly the way it is designed and described in the documentation: "na.omit returns the object with incomplete cases removed."

a <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
b <- c(2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20)
c <- c(0.1, 3, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
d <- c(3, 6, 9, 10, 12, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)

df <- data.frame(a, b, c, d)
df[!(is.na(df$c) & is.na(df$d)),]



Here's a scalable way to do this in dplyr. You can include the columns that you want to consider for omission (cols_to_be_ommitted ) and use filter with if_any to keep the rows which has at least one non-NA value.
library(dplyr)
cols_to_be_ommitted <- c("c", "d")

df %>% filter(if_any(all_of(cols_to_be_ommitted), Negate(is.na)))

#  a  b   c  d
#1 1  2 0.1  3
#2 2  4 3.0  6
#3 3  6 5.0  9
#4 4  8  NA 10
#5 5 10  NA 12


i will like to add a simple solution you can implement using dplyr's filter function like this:
a <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
b <- c(2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20)
c <- c(0.1, 3, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
d <- c(3, 6, 9, 10, 12, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)

df <- data.frame(a, b, c, d)

# filter out rows where both c and d have NA
library(dplyr)

df_filtered <- df %>% filter(!(is.na(c) & is.na(d)))

df_filtered

result set:
> df_filtered
  a  b   c  d
1 1  2 0.1  3
2 2  4 3.0  6
3 3  6 5.0  9
4 4  8  NA 10
5 5 10  NA 12


What does this add over the two previous answers?
